# Integration of RASA Chatbot on Android Application

Tags: artificial-intelligence, rasa-nlu, rasa-core, rasa, rasa-x

My question is that I am developing an AI Powered Banking Chat-bot using RASA, Can anyone guide me how to deploy it or integrate it on an Mobile Application (Android)?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Provide examples and code please.

Comment: What sort of example? I am developing an Chatbot for my final year project and it's front end's gonna be on android. So, I need to know how will I be able to connect by bot(which is developed on python) can be integrated/deployed to my Android Application.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you use retrofit/Gson, if not it's easy to get the idea
at first you need to retrive JWT token, for that you need to call

```
    @POST("api/auth/jwt")
    fun authenticateAsync(@Body authRequest: AuthRequest): Deferred<AuthResponse>
```

where AuthRequest is

```
data class AuthRequest(
    @SerializedName("conversation_id")
    @Expose
    val conversation_id: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
    @SerializedName("chat_token")
    @Expose
    val chat_token: String
)
```

where conversation id is some random string, chat_token is the token when you share the bot, smth like `87f7d34f9aa74d51asdqwe27fac62c44`

after getting jwt token you can post messages with

```
@POST("api/conversations/{conversation_id}/messages?environment=production")
fun postMessageAsync(
    @Header("Authorization") token: String,
    @Path("conversation_id") conversation_id: String,
    @Body messageRequest: MessageRequest
): Deferred<List<ChatMessageResponse>>
```

where

```
data class MessageRequest(
    @SerializedName("message")
    @Expose
    val message: String
)
```

and

```
data class ChatMessageResponse(
    @SerializedName("recipient_id")
    @Expose
    val recipient_id: String,
    @SerializedName("text")
    @Expose
    val text: String,
    @SerializedName("externalFields")
    @Expose
    val externalFields: List<String>,
    @SerializedName("custom")
    @Expose
    val custom: CustomResponseData? = null
)
```

Hope it was helpful